# Sum the occurance of string in column in csv file via pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sum

I have a csv file in this format:

| file_name | pred_class |
| --- | --- |
| First | pound |
| Second | sterling |
| Third | pound |
| Fourth | pound |

After loading the file via `pandas`, and running this code:

```
total = (df['pred_class'] == 'pound').sum()
print(total)
```

I get this error

`raise UnsupportedArrayTypeException(type_name) console_thrift.UnsupportedArrayTypeException: UnsupportedArrayTypeException(type='int64')`

Can you tell me how to correctly get the sum without this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try compare numpy array, but your solution for me working perfectly:

```
total = (df['pred_class'].to_numpy() == 'pound').sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
len(df[df['pred_class'] == 'pound'])
```

or use:

```py
sum(i == True for i in df['pred_class'] == 'pound')
```

Your formula is working perfectly for me though.

Comment: Yes, edited my answer, the formula above works perfectly for me too.